# react-apollo providing data and mutation to the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, apollo, react-apollo

I used to use prevues version of where I could use connect to provide data and mutation methods to component like so:

```
export default connect({
  mapQueriesToProps,
  mapMutationsToProps,
})(component);
```

And in each `mapQueriesToProps` and `mapMutationsToProps` I could provide many instance for example 2-3 data queries and several mutation methods.

But how can I do it using following pattern in the new version?

```
export default graphql(data, {
  options: ({ params: { id } }) => ({
    variables: {
      id: Number(id),
    },
  }),
})(component);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `compose` several times.

Compose all the mutations and all the queries and then compose them in your component.